# How to store sensor data?

Tags: ms-access, database-design, database-schema

I am building a database for a biomedical device researcher. The study is complete, so no more data will be added and now he is wanting it organized. I begun to map out the relationships and realize I am stuck. How can I connect everything?

- 1 participant wears 1 brace.
- 1 brace has 2 types of sensors. One takes impedance measurements (resistance and reactance), one takes contextual measurements (battery, temp, humidity and acceleration).
- Each measurement is taken approximately every 2.5 minutes for however long the participant wears the brace (avg 8 hours/day):
  [image: The impedance data format]
  [image: The contextual data format]
- 1 resistance and reactance measurement is taken at many frequencies (ranging from 1kHz to 128kHz pictured below) 0R -1 impedance sensor takes measurements at 8 different frequencies (resistance and reactance).
- At 3 different locations (longitudinal, transverse, onBoard):
  ![The current storage of the 3 locations]
  My idea so far :

[image: Connecting Sensor data]

What's important :

- Time-series of every measurement.
- The day, participantID, location, measurement type, etc.
- In all there are 20 participants. There will not be any more added.
- I am using Microsoft Access.

***.mat File Structure for resistance and reactance***
(the 8 columns represent 8 unique frequencies)
[Resistance and Reactance structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS7Tu.png)

***.mat File Structure for Battery, Temperature, and Humidity***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKevT.png)

Comment: if you need a picture I can answer this but I will try just a comment.  First it looks like your relationships are backward. Each piece of sensor data can only come from one location but each location corresponds to many individual pieces of data.  Second if you remove frequency from SensorData you can put all your data in the SensorData table because all the data looks to be of type number/decimal.  see next comment

Comment: Day is a calculated variable and I suggest you treat it as such and add a function to the database to calculate Day.  Add a code module and add a public function like getDay(atime as DateTime).  When you need day just calculate it.  In a similar way frequency looks redundant with MeasurementType.  If you add a description to measurement type two descriptions might be id=1 desc= 20hzReactance and id = 2 desc = 20hzImpediance. so if you need  frequency 20hz add a function is20hz to the database.  Though in practice I seldom bother being explicit about such a simple function.

Comment: @mazoula First, thank you for you response! When you say "Day" is a calculated variable, what do you mean?  Also, one thing my professor is interested in is "I want to see the resistance data of participant 1007 from Day 1 at 8kHz from the longitudinal location."

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know more like what is in each *.mat file, non-functional requirements like performance, etc. But, given such a constrained resultset and that it is now static, here's a super normalized structure ([eraser](https://www.tryeraser.com)):

[image]

Forgive the casing, I have been working in Python a lot recently.

Start creating tables at the leafs (day, time, frequency, measurement type, sensor type, etc). Fill them with data.

Work your way to the left. If "Null" becomes necessary for a column value, stop.

Pseudocode to "get resistance data of participant 1007 from Day 1 at 8kHz from the longitudinal location":

```sql
    select mfv.measurement
    from log as l
    join log_frequency_measurement lfm as lfm on l.log_frequency_measurement_id = lfm.id
    join log_entry le on lfm.log_entry_id = le.id
    join participant p on le.participant_id = p.id
    join location l on le.location_id = l.id
    join day_time dt on le.day_time_id = dt.id
    join day d on dt.day_id = d.id
    join measurement_frequency_value as mfv on lfm.measurement_frequency_value_id = mfv.id
    join measurement_frequency as mf on mfv.measurement_frequency_id = mf.id
    join frequency f on mf.frequency_id = f.id
    join measurement_sensor ms on mf.measurement_sensor_id = ms.id
    join sensor_type st on ms.sensor_type_id = st.id
    where f.value = 8
        and p.description = "1007"
        and d.value = 1
        and l.name = "Longitudinal"
        and st.type = "Resistance"
```

Depending on your version of Microsoft Access, you may be able to try pivot tables instead of complex queries. More information about that here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-pivottable-or-pivotchart-views-in-an-access-desktop-database-83e524df-dfbd-456d-9dd0-0a48c1aa6752

You mentioned "professor" so, in case this is homework, I would suggest considering what your professor may be looking for. Especially if they made a point to say such extreme normalization is a bad thing (normally it is in the typical enterprise due to performance/complexity/etc), they may be looking for a particular balance.